# Classdef and properties

Tags: matlab, matlab-class

For OO programming we use `classdef` in matlab.
Could someone explain to me how could I access the super class ? What is the role of properties, are they like constructors in Java?

Comment: I hate to be the grumpy old man, but you clearly didn't even google your questions.  You'll get much more helpful answers if you put in some effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `@` to access the superclass. From [Calling Superclass Methods on Subclass Objects](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/matlab_oop/bsa1q42.html):

```
classdef MySub < MySuperClass
   methods
      function obj = MySub(arg1,arg2,...)
         obj = obj@MySuperClass(SuperClassArguments);
            ...
      end % MySub
   end % methods
end % classdef
```

---

Properties are like member variables.  [Properties – Storing Class Data](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/matlab_oop/bqs27pp.html).

Comment: obj = obj@MySuperClass(SuperClassArguments); here to access to super class ,but how do can I access to any methods ? the @ is used to call a function declared in a function ?

Comment: It sounds like you have lots of introductory questions on classes.  The best thing for you to do now would be to read the MathWorks documentation and try some examples.  If you still don't understand, then ask again.

Answer (score 2):

To define a subclass you could look at the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help//matlab/matlab_oop/creating-subclasses--syntax-and-techniques.html)

Single inheritance:

```
classdef classname < superclassname
```

For multiple inheritance:

```
classdef classname < super1 & super2
```

Properties are more like instance variables in Java.